# How to use eval() to import components dynamically in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eval, dynamic-import

I am trying to import a class component from a js file placed in external storage dynamically,

**sample.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

var HeaderComponent=eval(`class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    render() {
       return <Text>This is header</Text>;
    }
}`)

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    render() {
       return <View>{HeaderComponent}</View>;
    }
}
```

when i run the above code, I got following error,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

this error apparently indicates the following return statement(which is inside eval()),

```
return <Text>This is header</Text>;
```

May i know if this is the right way of doing dynamic import?. If not, Please let me know the right way of doing the dynamic import in `react-native`.

Answer (score 0):

use import/export keywords. add export at the end of the file, and import at the top

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

class HeaderComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    render() {
       return <Text>This is header</Text>;
    }
}

class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    render() {
       return <View><HeaderComponent/></View>;
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score -1):

The eval() is basically a function that is used for doing Arithmetic operations, It can’t used for import a Component or any thing else,

[here's a link from where you can learn about eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

For import component you can do that with several ways

1. import statement:

```
import <Your Component Name> from '<Your Component Path>'
```

2. require()

```
const <Your Component Name> = require('<Your Component Path>')
```

you just need to add one of the above line at top of the files where you've declared other imports

Comment: is there any way to import any component dynamically which we don't know at run time.